# Facebook comments mirroring not working after 18.October 2016

Tags: facebook, comments

Please, do not know, whether Facebook made changes in the comments plugin?
Mirroring comments web - fan page not working from 18.October 2016.
In documentation i cannot find the answer.
Thank you

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet heard about any such changes. In support did not try to write?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/327412057614827/?__mref=message_bubble